# Is it possible to create a separate pull requests for each commit on a single local branch?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I used to work on a codebase with a specialized tool for submitting pull requests that's built on top of git. In fact, it's the only experience I have with creating pull requests.

This tool created a pull request for each distinct commit on a local branch.

I'm now working on a separate codebase and have to use git's native features, and I'm wondering if there's a way to reproduce this capability with the native capabilities?

For example, on my local `feature_branch`, I have `commit1, commit2, commit3`. I would like to create 3 pull requests corresponding to each commit and these pull requests are stacked on top of each other.

Based on my brief searches, it seems I'd have to create a separate local branch for each commit, push each local branch to remote, and create a pull request from each remote branch. I'm not sure how the stacking works in this case.

Comment: Pull requests don't exist in git at all. GitHub's are branch-to-branch, although the new [merge queue](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-02-08-pull-request-merge-queue-public-beta/) may do a lot of what you want.

Comment: Branches are cheap; they're just references to a commit. The idea that a branch is a *collection* of commits is a side effect of how we picture a merge: a commit that "rejoins" two separate chains of commits that diverged from a common ancestor.

Comment: Just make sure you merge your new branches "in order".

Answer (score 2):

"native capabilities"?

Not from git itself.

But GitHub has a [CLI `gh`](https://github.com/cli/cli), with a [`gh pr create` command](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_create) which you can use to emaulte your PR creation scenario, combined with [`git switch -c newBranch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch#Documentation/git-switch.txt--cltnew-branchgt).

And GitHub even has [merges train now](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-02-08-pull-request-merge-queue-public-beta/).